# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined at circleHover

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a d3 data visualization and Im getting the following error message in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
at circleHover
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
// csv data
var urlTwo = d3.csv("http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/data/info_v6.csv", 
function(data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Index = +d.Index;
    d.Name = +d.Name;
    d.Characteristics = +d.Characteristics;
    d.Classification = +d.Classification;
    d.DateOfBirth = +d.DateOfBirth;
    d.Imgurl = +d.Imgurl;
    d.Location = +d.Location;
    d.Latitude = +d.Latitude;
    d.Longitude = +d.Longitude;
    d.MethodOfMurder = +d.MethodOfMurder;
    d.NumberOfVictims = +d.NumberOfVictims;
    d.Status = +d.Status;
    d.VictimProfileRevised = +d.VictimProfileRevised;
    d.DateOfMurderRevised = +d.DateOfMurderRevised;
    d._id = +d._id;
    d.DateAtMurder = +d.DateAtMurder;
}); 
console.log(data[0]);
});

// Calling circleHover function here
setTimeout(function() {circleHover($.grep(urlTwo, function(d) {return 
d.Index == 680;})[0])}, 3.25*delay);

// circlehover function

function circleHover(chosen) {

if (modus == "Map"){
    d3.select("#callOut")
        .style("top", "570px")
        .style("left", "30px");
}
```

The line below is the one that fails

```
if (hoverType == "city") {d3.select("#callOutCity").html(chosen.Name + 
chosen.Imgurl);}
    d3.select("#td-name").html(chosen.Name);
    d3.select("#td-imgurl").html(chosen.Imgurl); 
    d3.select("#td-dob").html(numFormatTime(chosen.DateOfBirth));
    //d3.select("#td-dob").html(chosen.Date of birth);
    d3.select("#td-location").html(chosen.Location);
    d3.select("#td-characteristics").html(chosen.Characteristics);
    d3.select("#td-method-of-murder").html(chosen.MethodOfMurder);
    d3.select("#td-number-of-victims").html(chosen.NumberOfVictims);
    d3.select("#td-victim-profile").html(chosen.VictimProfileRevised);
    d3.select("#td-status").html(chosen.Status);

    d3.select("#callOut")
    .style("visibility","visible");

}//circleHover
```

I'm not sure why it's saying it cannot read property 'Name' of undefined because isn't urlTwo (my csv file) technically the 'undefined' variable here? (which I defined?)

Comment: do a search for "async loading d3", a lot has been there before you

Answer (score 0):

`d3.csv` function does not return a value. 
This line

```
var urlTwo = d3.csv("http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/data/info_v6.csv",
```

leaves urlTwo still undefined. You should move your code to be under (or called from) d3.csv's callback - right after you call `data.forEach`. This should work in that case (notice replaced urlTwo with data)

```
setTimeout(function() {circleHover($.grep(data, function(d) {return 
d.Index == 680;})[0])}, 3.25*delay);
```

-- Edit --
Here is the revised code:

```
// csv data

d3.csv("http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/data/info_v6.csv", 
function(data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Index = +d.Index;
      d.Name = +d.Name;
      d.Characteristics = +d.Characteristics;
      d.Classification = +d.Classification;
      d.DateOfBirth = +d.DateOfBirth;
      d.Imgurl = +d.Imgurl;
      d.Location = +d.Location;
      d.Latitude = +d.Latitude;
      d.Longitude = +d.Longitude;
      d.MethodOfMurder = +d.MethodOfMurder;
      d.NumberOfVictims = +d.NumberOfVictims;
      d.Status = +d.Status;
      d.VictimProfileRevised = +d.VictimProfileRevised;
      d.DateOfMurderRevised = +d.DateOfMurderRevised;
      d._id = +d._id;
      d.DateAtMurder = +d.DateAtMurder;
  }); 

  // Calling circleHover after the data has loaded
  setTimeout(function() {circleHover($.grep(data, function(d) {return 
  d.Index == 680;})[0])}, 3.25*delay);
});

// circlehover function
function circleHover(chosen) {
if (modus == "Map"){
    d3.select("#callOut")
        .style("top", "570px")
        .style("left", "30px");
}
```

Comment: so what you are suggesting is first define var UrlTwo like this:                                   
var urlTwo = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/data/serial_killers/info_v6.csv";                
and then put this line: setTimeout(function() {circleHover($.grep(data, function(d) {
  return d.Index == 680;})[0])}, 3.25*delay);                                                                under d.DateAtMurder ... ?

Answer (score -2):

Are you 100% sure one of your data-point in the CSV file has `Index` value `680`?

Otherwise `$.grep` will return an empty array and indexing it with `[0]` will return `undefined`.